Cleaning rat poison? (UK)
So i rent a studio in an old house, carpets everywhere, barely got through to the landlord to change the kitchen to anything but carpet....
Been here for like 5 years, about 2 years ago i though i had a mouse/rat problem. placed poison around it was never touched, but there are definitely holes, since before i've been here.
I definitely heard & saw one last Saturday (9 days ago) - same day i noticed it started eating some of the 2 year old poison packets, but ate through 4 of them, which are supposed to be single-feed kill, without dying for a week... Placed some fresh ones next to the old ones without cleaning anything 5 days ago, haven't heard of it for over two days and the old nor the new poison have been touched. Plugged any holes I found... (off-topic) Do you think it's gone?
But to the main question, some of the poison that's been nibbled on and powderised along with untouched pellets being spilled around, I want to clean it up. Given that the poison says your skin shouldn't touch it, i'm scared that vacuuming it up will throw it up in the air and inhaling it is worse, since it's on carpet i have very few ideas as to how to clean it out, any ideas?

Reads like a horror story. They will usually make it back to the nest and die there. You will know it by rotting smell

Hopefully there's no nest in my walls

It seems that the old stuff has lost its potency, so the powder is probably not a hazard.
The active ingredient "warfarin" is not a cumulative poison so a small exposure will not pose any long term hazard.
consider other means of collecting the dust, (eg: use a brush or a damp paper towel)
